# Performing Multicriteria Analysis Using Distance Along Road Network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, spatial-analyst, analysis, network-analyst

There is the possibility that I will be working on a project which will look at thousands of properties in a region and measure their accessibility to different services (schools, parks, hospitals, etc).  The idea is that this will highlight properties which are best serviced and properties which need better services.  I've decided that a raster-based multi-criteria analysis would be ideal for this task.

For previous MCA which I have performed, I've always used the Euclidean Distance for calculating distance from objects (water, forests, etc).  However, for this example, this doesn't really make a lot of sense since the services would most likely be accessed via the existing road network.

In the past, I have also performed an accessibility analysis using the Two Step Floating Catchment Area Method ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step_floating_catchment_area_method) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19576837)) to determine accessibility to doctors.  I used the road network (with Network Analyst Extension) for this process.  The accessibility was applied to a suburb level, not to an actual property. I was thinking I may need to create an attribute for accessibility to all of these services for each property.  I could potentially weight them as another attribute.  However, an answer to [Performing Multicriteria Analysis using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25976/7424) states that a raster approach is more ideal.

Is there a way to incorporate the accessibility to these services in the form of a raster?

Note, we have not yet got the job and I do not have any data to post.  Let me know if more clarification is needed.

I have ArcGIS and could potentially use the Spatial Analyst and Network Analyst Extensions.

Comment: For me it seems that Network Analyst is the best for you if the services really will be accessed via road network. As for rasters, maybe you can do this through Cost surfaces (check one of the answers here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33799/how-to-create-paths-within-a-boundary)

Comment: Just trying to do the same myself (as in distance for facilities into an MCA). I am looking to use service area generation to create the distance/cost surface by setting a number of default breaks and dissolving ("Merge by break value") polygons ("rings"). I am trying to work with time (minutes) so I have setup speed and FT_Minutes TF_Minutes attributes in the network road data set. I will then convert the output polygon data set to a raster data set for inclusion in the MCA model. I say that I am currently going to do this but I am currently battling with the dud topology on the road data set

Comment: I would love to see your results and screenshots once you've completed this. Or even some intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks for joining in, Nick. However, your post does not seem to be an answer, nor does it appear to contain a question.  I have converted it into a comment for you.